# Create a formula/equation for linear pricing reduction

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm trying to create a formula/equation that can be used (in MS Excel) to price for goods based on quantity.  Apologies if I've used the wrong tag, I don't know what the *actual* definition of this problem is.

The pseudo logic is as follows:

1. For 100 items or less, price per unit is 50.00 (currency is not relevant yet)
2. For 2500 or more, the price per unit is 35.00
3. Between 101 - 2499, and equation should calculate a price in-between these boundaries such that the price-per-unit decreases as the quantity increases.  This decrease should be linear.

I've been searching for help for a couple of days, and my head is spinning (it's probably so simple but I'm missing something).  In Excel I've crafted [a spreadsheet to demonstrate](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2A562CFE564E2506!1319&authkey=!AJpf_FDkOEaHSdI&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) what I need to achieve (the grey prices are made up to create the drop - this is the bit I need to automate).

[image]

I would appreciate any help in either solving this or advice on whether I'm even attempting something that can be achieved.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this, the correct terminology is *"Linear Interpolation"*, and there's a fantastic example here  http://www.blueleafsoftware.com/Products/Dagra/LinearInterpolationExcel.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to define a function as follows:

\begin{equation}f(x) = \begin{cases}
  50.00 & \mbox{ for } x \leq 100\\
  35.00   & \mbox{ for } x \geq 2500 \\
  \alpha x + \beta & \mbox{ for } 100 < x < 2500
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

What we need to consider/calculate here is the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for the linear decreasing bit.

As it is linear, it should not be too hard to do so. Also, this means that our $\alpha$ here, will be our 'slope'.

Let us use the points $$(100,50.0) \mbox{ and } (2500, 35.0)$$

Therefore, $$\alpha = \frac{50.0 - 35.0}{100 - 2500} = -0.00625 $$

We know that $$f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$$

Now, if we re-arrange this, we get $$\beta = f(x) - \alpha x$$

Let us sub in our points (100, 50)

$$\beta = 50 - (-0.00625)(100) = 50 + 0.625 = 50.625$$

Therefore, $$f(x) = -0.00625x + 50.625$$

We can test this for both or given points:$$f(100)=50 \quad f(2500) = 35$$

Therefore, our new $f(x)$ can be defined as follows:

\begin{equation}f(x) = \begin{cases}
  50.00 & \mbox{ for } x \leq 100\\
  35.00   & \mbox{ for } x \geq 2500 \\
  -0.00625x + 50.625 & \mbox{ for } 100 < x < 2500
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

You should just integrate this function into Excel using general Excel operations.

Comment: Just to make sure its clear here. The f(x) function returns the price per unit. Do  you know how to integrate that into Excel?

Comment: Hi EvilDr. There was an issue with my $\beta = 50$ which has now been corrected. If we don't calculate $\beta$ then we can't calculate the unit price as we need beta for the calculation. If $\beta = 0$ then that would mean the line passes through the origin which does not fit in with what we are calculating.

Comment: Thanks.  This is really interesting, because if I change the lower price (to  `15.00 for x≥ 2500` then the total price changes so that its cheaper for 2500 units than it is for 2000 units.  I guess that's an issue with the price decrease?

Comment: Yeah that would be more to do with the limitations of the prices chosen. Obviously, it would be more economically suitable to choose a price that doesn't cause something like this to happen. It would depend on the circumstances of where the model in been used on which values/prices you would use.

Comment: Thanks very much - lovely answer and explanation.  We've got tired brains trying to figure out economies of scale effectively to decide on a price that provides some discount for larger purchases...